# PHP exec() doesn't seem to run when using crontab

Tags: php

I'm on a centos7 server, i have a command line program in php that uses exec() to run a node program.

Simply like this:

```
exec('node ' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/process_orders/process_orders.js ' . $order->uniqID . ' ' . $outputPath);
```

The strange thing is, that it works perfectly fine until i run the php program via a cron job, in the crontab i have this:

```
* * * * * dev1 /usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/php /dev1/_cli/process_orders.php > /dev1/_cli/process_orders.log &
```

The job runs, the php code itself runs, but once it gets to the exec line the node code never actually runs.

I'm a little confused if this is something to do with exec() or node, but since the node command works fine i'm assuming for some reason exec isn't running from the cron job

Comment: Try moving to another directory (such as `/`) and run the script as you have it in your crontab, and see if it works or gives an error message.

Comment: I know that crontab often have problems with things that are normally in the $PATH. Try to include the full node path. for example "/usr/local/bin/node" instead of just "node". btw: Your path could be different.

Comment: Also make sure the CLI install of php (which cron uses), allows `exec` in the first place. Possibly look for the `disable_functions` ini setting.

Answer (score 2):

When running job from `cron`, the current working directory, search path and other environment variables are different to when you run directly from CLI/web due to security measures and inconsistencies in configuration.

Add following to the start of the script and run it from cron/CLI to see all the differences.

```
var_dump(getcwd());
var_dump(getenv());
```

Also, capture standard error output from running `node`, it would give you hint to what the problem is.

```
$cmd = dirname(__FILE__) . '/process_orders/process_orders.js ' . $order->uniqID . ' ' . $outputPath;
exec('node ' . $cmd . ' 2>&1', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Most likely you'll see that `cron` drops `PATH` environment variable and your `node` binary can't be found.

In that case just use absolute path to `node` binary in `exec` arguments - that'll help.

To find a path to `node` binary you can run following script from CLI (not from cron!) to check where on your path does it located.

```
$ cat whereisnode.php
<?php
var_dump(exec('whereis node'));
?>
$ php whereisnode.php
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "node: /usr/bin/node"
}

...
$ cat process_orders.php
<?php
chdir(__DIR__);

$cmd = dirname(__FILE__) . '/process_orders/process_orders.js ' . $order->uniqID . ' ' . $outputPath;

exec('/usr/bin/node ' . $cmd . ' 2>&1', $output);
var_dump($output); 
?>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the input, i have actually tried the full path to node, didn't make a difference. I'll look at gathering more info from the output and see what it says